# Is it a good practice to make an index on every column that's used on a WHERE condition in a SQL database?

Tags: sql, database

The question says it all. I've ever put indexes for columns that I used on WHERE statements for optimization and help sites scale nicely. I'm talking with my co-worker who says it's best to not put those indexes and leave place for optimization when needed.
What do you think it's the best practice here?

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with your coworker.  Reserve the indexing for when you actually need it because your query is not performing to your needs. Make sure you have defined your PK & FK relationships, and those will be properly indexed.

Comment: Indexing each column individually is usually pointless. Various approaches to finding the balance were discussed in [Indexing from start or when performance problem arises?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6883/indexing-from-start-or-when-performance-problem-arises/6886#6886) on [dba.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I have to say that all the answers complete the big picture so I also placed various +1s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer, as always, is "it depends".

If the WHERE clause uses a column in such a way that indexing is broken, then why bother?  You'll want to rewrite those, if possible.

Indexes have to be calculated when you INSERT, so there's a cost to be weighed against querying.  If you read mostly, then indexing might make sense.  If your database is heavily transactional, indexes will slow down INSERTs.  Especially bulk uploads.

Comment: Can you give an example of a WHERE that's impossible to index?

Comment: Look at this http://blog.cnizz.com/2008/08/08/using-functions-in-mysql-where-clauses-breaks-speed-gains-from-indexing/ and this: http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/GUID-E35887BB-7E58-438C-AA27-97B2CDE7E069/GUID-AF5A75D7-0687-546C-87B2-0B7DF7D33217.html

Comment: Those are examples of optimizing your use of an index -- or, in the first case, making sure the data types match. But any WHERE expression can be indexed. For example, if you commonly use a clause like `WHERE upper(name) = ?`, you can index `upper(name)` and the database will use it.

Comment: @BarryBrown: a `WHERE` that combines 2 or 3 range conditions is hard to optimize: `WHERE (a < 67) AND (b > 56) AND (c BETWEEN 5 AND 10)` It depends on the DBMS but most will not use all 3 indexes (even if you have them) but only one of them.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best practice here is to put a few indexes in initially, as best-guesses for what indexes will be needed. But after that, you want to actually measure which queries are slow and index those. Maybe your where clauses, or even your entire queries will change as requirements change.

This could be as easy as using something that aggregates query time over the course of a day, like [pgfouine](https://github.com/overplumbum/pgfouine).

[image]

Comment: -1 for "guess which indexes will be needed" +1 for "actually measure which queries are slow and index those" = +0

Answer (score 3):

I'd have to say no: It's not a good practice to simply index every column because it happens to appear in a `WHERE` clause.

To start with, if you have two columns in a particular `WHERE` clause, you might have a decision as to whether to index both in the same index and which one to be the first column.  Just with a single column, the choice of `ASCENDING` or `DESCENDING` in an index could be important.  When the same table participates in many queries, and lots of columns in `WHERE` clauses, do you want to have multitudes of indexes with all these columns in various combinations and orders just because the columns appear in a `WHERE` clause?  No.

I would say that it **is** a good practice to design your indexes **taking into account** which columns are used in a `WHERE` clause, but ultimately, columns which may not appear in the `WHERE` clause but appear in a `JOIN` may be more significant to most of your indexes.  You can certainly design some indexes with inspection, but in general, you are going to want to actually profile your processes and see which indexes are actually useful to the bulk of the workload.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** It depends on the selectivity of the column. For example, there is no use indexing a column EMPLOYEE.GENDER. Probably not for COLLEGE_STUDENT.YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_STATUS (4 likely values) either.

If there are a few rare values scattered with one or two common values, you could have a partial index.

I would definitely index any field used in a query where no value is in more than 10% of the rows.